# streams, stream_bufs, codecvt facets and \n to \r\n translation

Tags: c++, iostream, streambuf, codecvt

What part of the C++ IO streams does the `\r` to `\r\n` conversion? Is it the `stream_buf` itself or is it part of the internal to external encoding conversion by `codecvt` facet?

**UPDATE 1**

You all say that it is done in streambuf/filebuf. Ok. But how does this arrangement deal with, e.g., external encodings like UTF-16? Then it seems that the file has to be opened with `ios::binary` flag which disables the translation.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\n` to `\r\n` conversion? Usually what you'll get from portable code is a `\n` and you need to prepend the line feed for "windows like" representations.

Comment: To prepend the extra `\r` has nothing to do with the used character encoding, it's still an extra character. The `\r` controls a terminal write cursor to start at column 0 for some terminals. `codecvt` controls how many bytes are used to encode a single character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This conversion is not (usually) performed by stream, streambuf, or facet. It is the responsibility the C library code (e.g. `fputc()`) that is called by streambuf's `overflow()` and `underflow()`.

If you need it for some reason (e.g. when implementing a dos2unix routine), there's a handy example in [boost.iostreams.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/tutorial/unix2dos_filters.html)

EDIT: `std::filebuf` only supports multibyte encodings for text files, e.g UTF-8 or GB18030 or whatever the locale uses. A UTF-16 file would have to be opened in binary mode, as a plain byte stream (which can be interpreted as UTF-16 with C++11's codecvt facilities), and yes the line endings would not get converted.

Comment: streambuf implementations don't necessarily need to use fputc(), this depends on the context. We have implementations for streambuf that directly output to a UART for debugging purposes, the (RT)OS used doesn't even provide file handles, so how to use fputc() then??

Comment: @g-makulik The streambuf used by `std::cout` in particular is required to use the same underlying buffer as what the C I/O uses when writing to `stdout`, so this would be non-standard. As for filebuf and other streambufs, well, that's what my "usually" was for.

Answer (score 1):

IFAIR it's done in streambuf implementation, `codecvt` just deals with the locale representation specifics.

Comment: Same comment as to Éric Malenfant's answer: Why is it done in filebuf? Does that not mean that filebuf has to have some knowledge of external encoding provided by codecvt facet?

Comment: It has nothing to do with character encoding IMHO, but how the OS handles line endings in terminal displays.

Answer (score 1):

It is performed by std::filebuf, if it was open without the ios::binary flag.

Comment: Why is it done in `filebuf`? Does that not mean that `filebuf` has to have some knowledge of external encoding provided by `codecvt` facet?